# What are the long term benefits of Blood Devolution?

Tags: mary-skelter-nightmares

According to the game, Blood Devolution makes characters "stronger" by lowering their level. However, I devolved Sleeping Beauty and the only benefit I've noticed is that I was able to reallocate her skill points;  after painstakingly bringing her back up to speed, she doesn't seem any stronger.

Am I missing something? What are the benefits of devolving a character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some more research, it looks like you get *bonus* skill points when you Devolve a character. I constantly leave my character's with leftover skill points to learn more costly skills, so I must not have noticed. It also looks like using Blood Devolution to delevel a character for more levels at a time gives better bonuses.

From [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/188003-mary-skelter-nightmares/75803765):

> devolving just gives you a point reset and adds bonus points so you can respec at later levels should you wish.

And from [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/188003-mary-skelter-nightmares/75838704):

> I had try this system it seem to reset your skill, level down (I choose 15) and got bonus skill point 
>   for example
>
> I choose Alice Level 20 she now level 5 her skill point is 8 (which normally should be 5 right?) and when I level back to 20 it seem her stat is higher by 1

---

> Yes the blood crystal cost is much higher at higher levels. Doing a level 80 delevel got Kaguya 66 points to play around with. Do note any points put in Massacre skills do not seem to be refunded and are kept in whatever state they were in or at least it seems that way to me.

---

> OK I can confirm that your skill point and stat will stack each time you devolve